# xPages with FTSearch memory leak

Tags: javascript, xpages, lotus-domino

My xPage has a repeat control that use ARRAY as a data source. This array gets values from FTSearch. The problem is that it makes Domino server crash because OutOfMemory exceptions.

REPEAT:

```
<xp:repeat id="ssRepeat" var="rData" indexVar="rIndex" value="#{javascript:getMyDocs()}">
```

DATA SOURCE SSJS:

```
function getMyDocs(){
    .............

    var myArr = new Array();

    var dc:NotesDocumentCollection = db.FTSearch(<......>, 100);

    var doc:NotesDocument = dc.getFirstDocument();  
    var tmpdoc:NotesDocument = null;


    while (doc != null) {
        var xx = doc.getItemValueString("xx");
        var yy = doc.getItemValueString("yy");
        var zz = doc.getItemValueString("zz");
        var ww = doc.getItemValueString("ww");

        myArr.push([xx, yy, zz, ww, vv]); 

        tmpdoc = dc.getNextDocument(doc);
        doc.recycle();
        doc = tmpdoc;

    }
    .............

    dc.recycle();    
    return myArr;
}
```

Do you see anything wrong in my code? Is this a right approach?

```
Note:
1. There can be multiple repeats on the page that use getMyDocs() function to find documents (based on search parameters).
2. FT index is really huge ~1Gb because the db is ~50Gb.
3. Do I recycle() everything right?
```

I cannot figure out why Domino looses its memory... (v9.0.1 FP6)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of improvements you can make to your application. In no specific order:

- move your logic to a JavaBean
- let the bean cache the array values, so it executes only once in the application lifecycle

  - use FTSearch against a view that has the columns you need, so you can use ViewEntries instead of documents
  - check carefully: if a returned item was a Datetime it needs recycling too
  - increase the Java heap size on the server

Comment: Thank you stwissel. Well, if one of xx, yy.. etc is Datetime then where do I recycle it in my example above? I don't want to put NULL values in myArray that the function returns

Answer (score 1):

Memory and recycling are different issues. OutOfMemory is an issue with Java heap size, with the memory size required for the Java objects that are being serialized. "PANIC: Lookup handles out of range" is the indicator for a recycling issue.

You are doing an FTSearch for 100 documents and getting four values, so unless those are very long strings, it seems strange that would cause memory issues.

Check persistence settings. "Keep All Pages In Memory" is going to impact Java memory. Also, if you have XAgents in the application and are not setting `viewState="nostate"`, those will also be kept in memory and could impact the application. Any pages used as REST services will also have the same impact. XAgents and REST are by definition stateless, so serializing them is pointless.

Reducing the length of time sessions are persisted and using Keep Session Alive control will also benefit memory, because the component trees for sessions where a browser is closed will get dumped more quickly. By default, they will not get dumped until 30 minutes after the browser is closed.

All these will be documented in Mastering XPages Second Edition chapters on performance, and equally in slides from various sessions about XPages performance.

Comment: Isn't OutOfMemory also thrown when Domino's shared memory allocation and local process stack and heap memory exhaust the server's virtual address space so that when the JVM tries to allocate a page for heap it gets a failure even though it would be within the configured JavaMaxHeapSize?  (Maybe a non-issue now on a 64 bit OS, but last time I remember looking into it, one of the engineers told me that yes, Domino is 64 bit, but not really fully taking advantage of it.)

Comment: Our Domino admins took care of JavaMaxHeapSize.. And seems it helps. But I'll watch Domino logs few more days.... Sorry, but where do I set viewState="nostate"?

Comment: In an XPage, on the All Properties tab. It's a property of the XPage itself, so you need to select that in the Outline or have no component selected.

Answer (score 1):

Change `doc.getNextDocument(doc);` to `dc.getNextDocument(doc);`